# Seeking advice on optimizing ActiveRecord::destroy_all

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5, rails-activerecord

Rails 5+

I'm aware that `destroy_all` instantiates every model and runs `destroy` on it and that `delete_all` is faster, but deleting doesn't respect:

- `before_destroy`, `around_destroy` and `after_destroy` callbacks
- `dependent` settings on relationships

Assuming that list is comprehensive, shouldn't we be able to save time with `destroy_all` by checking these properties of the model and if there are no callbacks, just address the relationships as needed?

edit: I'm looking for a way to modify the default `destroy_all` behaviour so that it's smarter and doesnt blindly instantiate all objects and chain calls to dependent relationships. If we have relationship A with dependent B (1:1), and A is large (1 mil) that's a lot of objects to instantiate and destroy. Yes, application/domain specific knowledge means you can just call `delete_all` but if someone changes the model and adds relationships, that `delete_all` just became very dangerous. If we optimize `destroy_all` to do some thinking, we can reduce a simple `dependent: delete` relationship to two `delete_all` calls (A and B) from a single `destroy_all` on relation A, where the original `destroy_all` would be 2 million object instantiations and DB hits.

```
# Pseudocode
# Let the model in question be `User`

ids = self.pluck(:id)
if model.has_destroy_callbacks  # I imagine there's some fancy introspection stuff I can use 
  original_destroy_all
  return
else
  # Check Restrict type
  model.restrict_relationships.each do |rel|
    other_models = some_cute_query
    raise_exception_or_add_error if other_models.any?
  end

  # Add some check here to make sure we didn't miss any unknown dependency type

  # Normal relationships
  model.non_restrict_relationships.each do |rel|
    dep_type = rel.dependent_type
    if dep_type == :destroy
      rel.where(model_id: ids).destroy_all
    elsif dep_type == :delete
      rel.where(model_id: ids).delete_all
    elsif dep_type == :nullify
      rel.where(model_id: ids).update_all(model_name_id: nil)
    end
  end
end
self.delete_all # i.e. the collection that was gonna get destroyed
```

What I'm looking for is sanity checks on if I'm missing something obvious as to why this won't work. I'm also looking for suggestions on how I can shimmy this into ActiveRecord. Also, can you specifically override the `destroy_all` for collections/relationships on specific models?

Answer (score 1):

> The callback chain is accessible via the `_*_callbacks` method on an
>   object. Active Model Callbacks support `:before`, `:after` and
>   `:around` as values for the kind property. The kind property defines
>   what part of the chain the callback runs in.
>
> To find all callbacks in the before_save callback chain:
>
> ```
> Topic._save_callbacks.select { |cb| cb.kind.eql?(:before) }
> ```
>
> - [Rails API Docs: ActiveRecord::Callbacks](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Callbacks.html)

So in this case its `_destroy_callbacks` but I would make the method raise an exception and bail instead of calling `destroy_all` if your goal is a sanity check.

```
raise SomeKindOfError if model._destroy_callbacks.any?
```

That's far more helpful in terms of debugging and usage instead of just burying the problem.

Getting all the associations of model can be done via [`.reflect_on_all_associations`](https://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Reflection/ClassMethods.html#method-i-reflect_on_all_associations) which gives you AssocationReflection objects. From there you can get the options of the association.

### But...

This reeks of "clever" code. When you get to the point where using destroy callbacks is a performance problem there are bigger problems then just choosing between `delete_all` or `destroy_all` and automatically choosing does not really address the problem at all.

Comment: Maybe my question wasn't clear. I'm trying for replacing destroy_all with this such that this is recursive.
Right now, if you call destroy_all on a collection with many records, each object gets instantiated and has to destroy associated objects. Given hypothetical collections A and B where there's a dependent: :destroy operation, and A and B have 1 million records, that's a lot of DB hits right? If we detect that we can delete_all twice, that's two DB calls vs 2mil obj instantiations and queries to delete.